# Find reversed names on a file with hadoop mapreduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, mapper, reducers

Hello I have this file http://aminer.org/lab-datasets/citation/citation-network1.zip and I need to find the names of the authors that have publications with just 2 authors and they reverse their names on at least one of them. 
The mapper I made is this one :

```
    package bigdatauom;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.StringTokenizer;
    import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
    import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
    import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;

public class TokenizerMapper 
extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
private Text keyAuthors = new Text();

public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context
        ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {    

    StringTokenizer authorslinetok = new StringTokenizer(value.toString(), "#");    

    while (authorslinetok.hasMoreTokens()) {
        String tempLine = authorslinetok.nextToken();

        if (tempLine.charAt(0) == '@') {
            tempLine = tempLine.substring(1);
            StringTokenizer seperateAuthorsTok = new StringTokenizer(tempLine, ",");
            ArrayList<String> authors = new ArrayList<String>();
            while (seperateAuthorsTok.hasMoreTokens()) {
                authors.add(seperateAuthorsTok.nextToken());
            }
            if (authors.size() == 2){
            keyAuthors.set(tempLine);
            context.write(keyAuthors, one);
            }
        }
    }

}
}
```

I need to have 2 instances of the reducer and have been working on this project for one week with no result.
Any advice is appreciated thanks in advance!

Comment: you can write a `CustomPartitioner` to redirect instances where `authors.size() == 2` to a single reducer

Comment: can you explain it a bit more I am very new to hadoop sorry. the reducer will just be the simple one wordcount has?

Comment: What do you need to do when `authors.size == 2` and when it's not?

Comment: I only need the publications that authors.size == 2. And then check if there is another publication that the 2 authors have reversed their names. For example 1st publication authors Alex, Nick and 2nd publication Nick,Alex and keep these names once in a file.

Comment: Dont know the algorithm that should be in hte reducer or what I need to change on the reducer of the wordcount in order to take the result I want.